# What exactly is happening in my for loop

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

This is my current code:

```
string userName = "";
        int v1 = 0, v2 = 0, v3 = 0, v4 = 0, v5 = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        float avg;
        float variance;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name:");
        userName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter in a number between 10 and 50: ");
        int inputCheck = 0;
        inputCheck = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i <= v5; i++)
        {
            if (i == v1)
            {
                v1 = inputCheck;
                if (v1 < 10 || v1 > 50)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The number you have entered is invalid please enter a new variable: ");
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (i == v2)
            {
                v2 = inputCheck;
                if (v2 < 10 || v2 > 50)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The number you have entered is invalid please enter a new variable: ");
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (i == v3)
            {
                v3 = inputCheck;
                if (v3 < 10 || v3 > 50)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The number you have entered is invalid please enter a new variable: ");
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (i == v4)
            {
                v4 = inputCheck;
                if (v4 < 10 || v4 > 50)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The number you have entered is invalid please enter a new variable: ");
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (i == v5)
            {
                v5 = inputCheck;
                if (v5 < 10 || v5 > 50)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The number you have entered is invalid please enter a new variable: ");
                }
                continue;
            }
```

I'm getting the console to correctly identify that if v1 is greater than 50 or less than 10 it gives the message. But the code stops and doesn't continue asking for variables. I've tried following what is happening in the for loop and the if's loop but I'm just getting lost. I'm tasked with getting 5 variables by using loops and one console.readlin();. If that helps at all as to why I'm asking this question.

Comment: look at what your loop is doing. All of your vX numbers are set to zero, your loop starts at 0, and they all do the exact same checks, meaning that on your first iteration ALL of the vX numbers will trigger your error.

Comment: If you think `v1 = inputCheck;` will read from console you are wrong

Comment: @Marc B: Yes I see what you mean thank you for pointing that out. Thank you for responding to my question.

Comment: @BojanKogoj: It doesn't? A fellow student had shared that with me, could you explain what exactly it's doing then? Thank you for responding to my question.

Comment: what is the point of votedown a question, when he is just trying to learn something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. As others have pointed out,

```
int v5 = 0;
for (int = 0; i < v5; i++) ...
```

Means you will never enter the for loop because `i < v5` is `false`.

Secondly, it seems like you're trying to loop through `v1` - `v5` as variables. This is not 
the correct way to perform a loop over an arbitrary number of variables. You will need an array or some other type of collection.

Probably what you want is something like this:

```
string userName = "";
int[] v= new int[5];
int sum = 0;
float avg;
float variance;

Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name:");
userName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please enter in a number between 10 and 50: ");

for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
{
    int inputCheck = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    while (inputCheck < 10 || inputCheck > 50)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The number you have entered is invalid please enter a new variable: ");
        inputCheck = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    v[i] = inputCheck;
}
```

Comment: So I have looked at adding what you have done here. When I run the program and enter in a variable I get an IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled message. I looked up what that error means, but I don't see how it pertains to this scenario.

Comment: There was an issue with the for-loop in my original code. `i <= v.Length` should've been `i < v.Length`. I've corrected it now.

Comment: Ahh okay, I believe I understand now why I would receive that error. I want to thank you for taking time and helping me. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Sorry for not thoroughly testing out my code before posting it.

Answer (score 2):

Some error in your loop :

1. `for (int i = 0; i <= v5; i++)` since v5 = 0, the loop will run only one time
2. `inputCheck = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` would only read the number once, and even if you fixed the loop to run `5 times`, the input asked from the user will be just once, hence needed to move `inputCheck = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` within the loop.
3. The check for input for 1 to 50 can be improved in the loop, since u have the same restriction for all the variables.

Try this way :

```
    string userName = "";
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0, v3 = 0, v4 = 0, v5 = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    float avg;
    float variance;

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name:");
    userName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter in a number between 10 and 50: ");
    int inputCheck = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        inputCheck = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        while (!(inputCheck < 10 || inputCheck > 50))
        {
             switch (i)
            {

                case 1:
                    v1 = inputCheck;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    v2 = inputCheck;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    v3 = inputCheck;
                    break;

                case 4:
                    v4 = inputCheck;
                    break;

                case 5:
                    v5 = inputCheck;
                    break;


            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: That did help quite a bit. I want to thank you for taking time and helping me further understand this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name:");` and the `userName = Console.ReadLine();` inside the beginning of the `for` loop if you want the input again.

Comment: I understand why you had said this, and it did help. I want to thank you for your time in helping me understand what I was doing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it looks like `v5` is 0, so your loop is gonna run only once!

```
for (int i = 0; i <= v5; i++) //this will be true only once because v5 = 0
```

Comment: Yeah I see what you are saying there. I guess I'm confused on what I should put there. He doesn't want any arrays or lists from what the directions say. I thought that this was going through each variable until it hit the 5th one. But apparently that isn't the case?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= v5; i++)
    {
        if (i == v1)
        {
            v1 = inputCheck;
            if (v1 < 10 || v1 > 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number you have entered is invalid please enter a new variable: ");
            }
            continue;
        }

        ...
     }
```

The loop will have only first iteration.
Because there is `continue;` in first iteration. 
`v5` will be 0 always.`i` will be changed to 1 after first `continue;` and then `i <= v5` - false (1 > 0 :) ), and loop will be completed.